# What was the Shopkeepers Loss

Tags: finance

Here is the problem :

> A lady buys goods worth 200 from a shop where the goods are sold non-profit.The lady gives the shopkeeper a 1000 rupee note . The shopkeeper gets the change from the next shop kepping 200 and giving the lady back 800 . Later the shopkeeper of the next shop comez saying the 1000 rupee note was duplicate and demands his money back.What was the shopkeepers loss?

My answer is 1000
Is it correct
Thankyou for your help.

Comment: The customer walked away with $800$ plus an item worth $200$. We have not been told how this loss of $1000$ will be shared between the two gullible shopkeepers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.  He must pay back the 1000 but he has 200 left after the 800 change he gave to the customer.  But that 200 is cancelled by the loss of the item he sold for 200 at "no profit."  So the net loss is 1000.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it